# what could I do to recover this external drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

On my computer management I see a disk that has not been initialized:

[image]

that belongs to an external drive - a WD Passport

[image]

when I click on `initialize disk`

[image]

[image]

I get an error message - the request failed with a hardware error

I check the event logs

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Virtual Disk Service
Date:          12/12/2019 18:27:33
Event ID:      10
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RADHE.mydomain
Description:
VDS fails to write boot code on a disk during clean operation. Error code: 800701E3@02070008
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Virtual Disk Service" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49664">10</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-12-12T18:27:33.680650300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>41693</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>RADHE.mydomain</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>800701E3@02070008</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

[image: recover this]

question:

Is there a way I can recover this external drive?

Should I change the cable and see if that works?

TIA

Comment: You may try with another cable but the result is likely to be the same.

Comment: is there any possible solution? anything I could do to assess the situation?

Comment: External drives have only two parts that can fail, the drive itself and the SATA-USB interface. In this case, without opening the enclosure, there's no other troubleshoot than test a different cable and/or test the unit in another PC. If the problem persists then you may try opening it and test the disk connected directly to a SATA port.

Comment: Please keep in mind that **typically** when the interface fails the drive isn't recognized at all. Yours still is and everything else strongly suggests the internal drive itself is what failed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia your comments could be put into an answer if you wish so, I would accept that answer.